# copying vector of pair

Tags: c++, vector, c++11

I am trying to copy a vector of pair to another:

```
vector<pair<int,int>> vp = {pair<int,int>(1,1), pair<int,int>(2,2)};
vector<pair<int,int>> vp2;
for_each(vp.begin(), vp.end(), [vp2](pair<int,int> p){
                                               if(/*some condition*/){
                                                vp2.push_back(p);
                                               }
                                              });
```

I get this compiler error:

```
error: passing ‘const std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::pair<int, int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> >, value_type = std::pair<int, int>]’ discards qualifiers
```

Using gcc 4.5.1 on ubuntu.

Comment: It might be a dumb question but wouldn't `vp2 = vp` just do the trick ?

Comment: @ereOn: He's looking for a `copy_if`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copying is much easier than that:

```
vector<pair<int,int>> vp2(vp.begin(), vp.end());
```

or even:

```
vector<pair<int,int>> vp2 = vp; // or
vector<pair<int,int>> vp2(vp);
```

The error in your code is that you capture `vp2` *by value* which effectively makes it `const` in your anonymous method, and you cannot call `push_back` on a `const vector`. The following should work:

```
for_each(vp.begin(), vp.end(), [&vp2](pair<int,int> p){vp2.push_back(p);});
```

But there’s no reason to use this instead of the simpler code.

Comment: Isn't `vector<pair<int,int>> vp2( vp );` even easier?

Comment: Even better: `vector<pair<int,int>> vp2(vp);`

Comment: @ybungalobill I don’t think it’s better (especially since this will sometimes run into the most vexing parse). But I’ll mention it for completeness’ sake.

Comment: Nevertheless, the question is how to make the original code work. Imagine that the OP wants to transform somehow the value before `push_back`.

Comment: Dint know that. Thanks. But what i am really doing is iterating over the first array and inserting the pairs depending on a condition. Let me update the code.

Comment: there is also std::copy of course which would be the preferred algorithm way of doing this if the copy ctor isn't an option

Comment: +1 for "But there’s no reason to use this instead of the simpler code." That is saying it nicely. If there was an IOC++11CC contest, the posted code would be a good candidate.

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative to Konrad's answer; if the goal is simply to copy the elements of the first vector if they match a certain condition, would `std::copy_if` not be a better match?

```
vector<pair<int,int>> vp = {pair<int,int>(1,1), pair<int,int>(2,2)};
vector<pair<int,int>> vp2;

copy_if(vp.begin(), vp.end(), back_inserter(vp2), [](pair<int,int> p) { return /* some condition */; });
```

Comment: +1 for_each is almost never the right answer, there is usally a better algo for what you want to do